# trace inequality of matrix

Tags: matrices, inequality

Let $Y\in R^{n\times p}$ with nonzero singular values($n\gt p$), $A=Y(1:p,1:p)$, $B=Y(p+1:n,1:p)$ are the submatrices of $Y$ such that
$$
 Y=\left(\begin{matrix}
A\\ B
\end{matrix} \right).
$$

$$
\Lambda=\left(\begin{matrix}
C & 0\\ 0 & D
\end{matrix} \right)
$$
where, $C=diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_p)$, $D=diag(\lambda_{p+1},\lambda_{p+2},\cdots,\lambda_n)$, $\lambda_1\gt \lambda_2\gt\cdots\gt\lambda_n\gt 0$.

Show that
\begin{equation}
\text{tr}\left( B^\top B(Y^\top Y)^{-1}A^\top C A(Y^\top Y)^{-2} -  A^\top A(Y^\top Y)^{-1}B^\top D B(Y^\top Y)^{-2}\right)\geq 0.
\end{equation}

Does anyone know how to prove this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true. Random counterexample: when
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&-2\\ -1&0},\ B=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 2&-2},\ \Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(6,3,2,1),
$$
we have
$$
\operatorname{tr}\left( B^\top B(Y^\top Y)^{-1}A^\top C A(Y^\top Y)^{-2} -  A^\top A(Y^\top Y)^{-1}B^\top D B(Y^\top Y)^{-2}\right)
=\frac{-39}{2\times7^3}<0.
$$

Comment: >o<, that sucks. Anyway, many appreciation for your counterexample.

Comment: I tried some other ways to prove my main theorem, but ended up with failure. So I still may have to use the inequality above to complete my proof. I am wondering whether imposing additional conditions would make this to be true. Do you have any insights about what these conditions are ?

Comment: @MaohuiLyu There are some obvious sufficient conditions, such as $Y^\top Y=I$ or $A^\top A$ commutes with $B^\top B$ etc., but I haven't any good remedy. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.